# Array Allocation Subscript Number

Tags: c++, c, arrays

Quick question regarding how memory is allocated.

If someone were to allocate 20 chars like this:

```
char store[20];
```

does this mean that it allocated 20 char type blocks of memory, or that it allocated char type blocks of memory starting with 0 and ending with 20. The difference is that the first example's range would be from store[0] to store[19], whereas the second example's range would be from store[0] to store[20].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means it allocated one block of memory large enough to hold 20 chars (from index 0 to 19)

Comment: Thanks. Setting this as answer because you were first.

Comment: Hm, I think he was last ;-) But hey, no problem ;-)

Answer (score 3):

[0] to [19] (20 elements, that is)

Answer (score 0):

The first - char store[20] allocates 20 chars, from 0 to 19.

Answer (score 0):

It allocates memory for 20 chars, i.e. valid indices go from 0 to 19.